# PHP laravel collections running flattened

Tags: php, laravel

Why does laravel not provide a function to run the maps of a collection one after each other instead of traversing over the items of the collection for each map.

An example of such a traversal can be seen here https://gist.github.com/more-pepsi/92aec3a2ecad3a8dce030c4a2ccecbb1

Please advise

How can I accomplish this with Collection native functions?

Comment: Not sure I understand the reasoning here. Doing a `->map($fn1)->map($fn2)` is both functionally and performance-wise identical to doing `->map(fn ($item) => $fn2($fn1($item)))`

Comment: But using laravel collections, function composition is not what it does. For each operation it traverses the array. Its time complexity is O(n*o) where o equals |operations|. Where, my example, using composition has O(n)

Comment: Traversing a length `n` array `o` times and applying `1` function each time is the same as traversing the `n` length array 1 time and applying `o` functions each time. It's both `O(o*n)`

Comment: Using composition in the matter you suggest is fine. It just reads better as a pipe, its not more readable to you?

Comment: I suppose yes, i'm wrong, my method is 0(n * o). But laravel collection is O(n * o + n * o) then. because it does have to make the operation to pull from the array the element its operating at, and with laravel collection it does this o*n times and makes o operations for each of n times.

Comment: I think that's subjective. I do understand the appeal. At any rate laravel does not have this natively. Laravel provides a [`Pipeline`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php)  class and you can probably [extend the collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#extending-collections) to work with this. Sidenote `O(n*o + n*o) = O(n*o)`.

Comment: How is O(n * o + n * o) = O(n*o)?

Comment: I did a test and using multiple traversals is slower then doing one. I mean not by much its its very noticeable over > 1e6 iterations

Comment: It's based on the big `O` notation definition. A `O(2n)` function is the same complexity class as an `O(n)`. Big-O is intended to measure an upper bound of how the function running time would grow when the input grows. In this case if `n` and `o` are very large numbers then both methodologies would more or less perform equally.

Comment: 10000 * 40 = 400000, 10000 * 41 = 410000. Difference of 10000, while n2, has a difference of 400000, if the inputs change n2 has a larger difference

Comment: Is there a link to part of the definition that states your point?

Comment: I get that Big o notation only measures the impact with regards to the input, but i'm not familiar with the academic specification as such

Comment: The wikipedia article is actually pretty good on Big-O [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Properties) is the property I used (*Multiplication by a constant*)